# Why 'var' % {1: 'variable'} prints 'var' instead of raising the exception TypeError as 'var' % (1,) does?

Tags: python, exception, logging, python-3.6

I was debugging my debug module, and I rely on a try ... catch to detect TypeError and format correctly log my message, then, I noticed that when dictionaries are passed, Python does not raise the traditional exception.

```
>>> 'var' % {1: 'variable'}
'var'
>>> 'var' % (1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

This is a minimal example with the logging module:

```py
import logging

class SmartLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):

    def _getMessage(self, remaining_arguments):

        try:

            if self.args:
                remaining_arguments.append( self.msg % self.args )

            else:
                remaining_arguments.append( self.msg )

            return False

        except TypeError as error:
            last = self.args[-1]
            self.args = self.args[:-1]
            remaining_arguments.append( str( last ) )

            if len( self.args ):
                return True

            else:
                remaining_arguments.append( self.msg )
                return False

    def getMessage(self):
        """
        Return the message for this LogRecord.

        Return the message for this LogRecord after merging any user-supplied
        arguments with the message.
        """
        remaining_arguments = []
        self.msg = str( self.msg )

        while self._getMessage( remaining_arguments ): pass
        return " ".join( reversed( remaining_arguments ) )

logging.setLogRecordFactory(SmartLogRecord)

var = 'SmartLogRecord'
logging.warning('I am a', var)

dumb = {1: 'variable'}
logging.warning('I am a', dumb)
```

Running it you get:

```
WARNING:root:I am a SmartLogRecord
WARNING:root:I am a
```

As you can notice, the last `dumb` message was lost.

Comment: OT: Do you really want to introduce a spelling error into your module to save two characters for the name of your variable? `remaing` really hurts my eyes and it is bad practice too.

Comment: I just had misspelled the name and did not noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the observed behaviour is in line with [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

> If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple
>   object. [5] Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number
>   of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object
>   (for example, a dictionary).

Note [5]:

> To format only a tuple you should therefore provide a singleton tuple
>   whose only element is the tuple to be formatted.

This explains that a tuple is accepted only if it exactly matches format string requirements. A tuple with one item which itself is not a tuple cannot possibly match any format string and always raise an exception.

It also explains that a dict is always accepted as a type, but may produce other errors.

---

And just for the case I'm wrong, there is a catch-all possibility that you have just discovere another "quirk". They warn explicitly:

> The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks
>   that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display
>   tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer formatted string
>   literals or the str.format() interface helps avoid these errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this problem I come up with the following solution:

```py
import sys
import logging

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    is_python2 = True
    from collections import MutableMapping
else:
    from collections.abc import MutableMapping

class SmartLogRecord(logging.LogRecord):

    def _getMessage(self, remaining_arguments):

        try:
            args = self.args

            if args:

                # if isinstance( args, dict ):
                if isinstance( args, MutableMapping ):
                    new_msg = self.msg % args

                    if new_msg == self.msg:
                        remaining_arguments.append( str( args ) )
                        remaining_arguments.append( new_msg )

                    else:
                        remaining_arguments.append( new_msg )

                else:
                    remaining_arguments.append( self.msg % args )

            else:
                remaining_arguments.append( self.msg )

            return False

        except TypeError as error:
            self.args = args[:-1]
            remaining_arguments.append( str( args[-1] ) )

            if len( args ) - 1 > 0:
                return True

            else:
                remaining_arguments.append( self.msg )
                return False

    def getMessage(self):
        """
        Return the message for this LogRecord.

        Return the message for this LogRecord after merging any user-supplied
        arguments with the message.
        """
        remaining_arguments = []
        self.msg = str( self.msg )

        while self._getMessage( remaining_arguments ): pass
        return " ".join( reversed( remaining_arguments ) )

logging.setLogRecordFactory(SmartLogRecord)

var = 'SmartLogRecord'
logging.warning('I am a', var)

dumb = {1: 'variable'}
logging.warning('I am a', dumb)
```

Which runs correctly:

```
WARNING:root:I am a SmartLogRecord
WARNING:root:I am a {1: 'variable'}
```